# 403 error when passing url as a parameter

Tags: php, http-status-code-403, url-parameters

I have a php file which doesn't establish database connection.

When I pass an url as a param like

```
 http://mydomain.com?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmyoranotherdomain.com
```

It shows a 403 error:

```
 You don't have permision to access blahblah.php file.
```

And when I remove the http part in param, it's alright like

```
 http://mydomain.com?q=myoranotherdomain.com
```

How can I let domains be passed in the url as params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to encode the url with:

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

You also have to do the decode:

```
string urldecode ( string $str )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

It's always this methode to encode parameter with special characters.

**Final Solution:**

I found this: [I get a 403 error when submitting "http://www." via GET. Even if it's encoded beforehand. Is there a solution for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481870/i-get-a-403-error-when-submitting-http-www-via-get-even-if-its-encoded-be?rq=1)

The answer is to replace the `http://www` String with something like: `htpwwwashere` in javascript and replace it again in your php. 
The reason - according to the link above - is some security stuff like to prevent injection attacks on the pages they're serving up.

Comment: Is there a difference between this method and encoding URL with JS? I use JavaScript to encode params

Comment: Maybe - What is the JS behinde your encoding

Comment: isn't my example link already encoded? or am I missing something? @Bart I already use it. I thought the problem maybe caused by httaccess configurations on the server

Comment: You did the encoding fine - but did you decode the parameter before you use it?

Comment: Of course I do. There's nothing wrong with special character encoding and decoding. Theproblem is only http in the param. I think it's a serverside security or something...

Comment: it's set 644 and I checked both 664 and 666. Doesn't help

Comment: I found something EXACTLY for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481870/i-get-a-403-error-when-submitting-http-www-via-get-even-if-its-encoded-be?rq=1

The answer is to replace the `http://www` String with something like `htpwwwashere` in javascript and replace it again in your php.

The reason - according to the link above - is some security stuff like to prevent injection attacks on the pages they're serving up.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. If it doesn't help, I'll talk to my host provider :)